# PHPExcel issue for reading date field from excel file

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am facing a problem with the PHPExcel class while i am using that class to read a excel file in my php code.

```
// Reading the excel data
$objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007();
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load('test.xlsx');
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$dataArray = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray();
```

I am using this code, Now problem is that when I create a excel file and insert a cell value like a date say 01/09/2012

and reads the full excelsheet using the toarray() function of PHPExcel class, then it do not returns the date value. it's returning a numeric value.

What I found that when we create the Excel file using the MS OFfice application and insert a date into any cell the excel converts the cell to a date format. So now I want to read a date format cell using the PHPExcel class.

Comment: The 'date format' you speak of is simply a formatted display version of the numeric values stored internally in Excel. Excel doesn't store '01/09/2012' and then convert it each time it needs to use the date in a calculation. it stores it in a native/numeric format and convers to the pretty string when it comes time to display it to you.

Answer (score 10):

**Rule one:**

It's not a good idea to set $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true); when you'll be working with dates. If you do that, then PHPExcel cannot tell you whether a cell contains a date or a number.

**Rule two:**

That number is an Excel date value as stored by Excel. The Excel numberFormat Mask then is used to convert that number to a formatted "human readable" date at display-time. (If you've used $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true); then you haven't loaded the cell's numberFormat mask.
If you've loaded the numberFormat masks, then you can use the getFormattedValue() method to return the formatted "human-readable" date as a string.

**Rule three:**

To convert an Excel numeric date value to a unix date/time stamp or to a PHP DateTime object, you can use the built-in PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP() or PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHPObject() methods.

**Rule four:**

All of this is fully documented. But I guess I'm going to have to write a special manual dedicated to Dates with the word DATES in big red letters in the filename.

Comment: Thanks , but now the issue with date is that i am using the code 
.........
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($dataToExport); 
.......
to generate the excel file. if i saw the data in my $dataToExport array the date is in format 'm/d/Y' say 09/13/2012 but when i export the excel file and check the date in excel file it looks like 2012-09-13. i want my date in excel same as present in array i.e 08/09/2012 . .....
...
> please suggest me how to define a column as date format using PHPExcel class becoz if i changed the exported excel column to date format it looks like same as i need.

Comment: If you're using fromArray() to set the worksheet data, then the value in your data array must already be the Excel date/time (numeric) value __or__ use the advanced value binder that will detect a string containing a date format, and convert it automatically for you... if you set the value in the array to the Excel numeric date value, then you'll need to set the number format mask for that data yourself, if you use the advanced value binder then it's set automatically to a default date/time mask

Comment: Thanks mark...I have an another issue can you plz help pe for that also....In my excel file i am trying to export a 16 digit credit card number with expory date. like i have 16 digit credit card as 1234567890123456 as Expiry date is 0112, now in excel i am getting the credit card number as 1.23457E+15 and when i double clicks on the excel cell i got the value 1234567890123500 which is not correct. Also expiry date do not have leading 0 . Expiry dare in excel is 112. I want in excel 16 digit right credit card number not the 1.23457E+15 code . and also expiry date with 0 i.e 0112

Comment: Numbers larger than PHP's maximum integer value need to be set explicitly as string values... but I hope you don't have my credit card number stored insecurely. For numbers with a leading zeroe, set an appropriate number format mask; or explicitly set as string... but you'll not be able to use fromArray() to do this, you'll have to do it cell by cell

Comment: is this possible to set a colum type to string or date type ?

Comment: A string is DataType PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING: you can set a cell value to an explicit datatype using the worksheet's setCellValueExplicit() or setCellValueExplicitByColumnAndRow() methods. Date type is not a type... dates are numbers, distinguished by the numberFormat mask of the cell.

Comment: Please read the PHPExcel documentation, and also look at the examples in the /Tests directory... it will explain a lot about how to use it. And please also read up about asking questions here on StackOverflow. If you have more questions to ask, ask them as questions rather than in comments against your original question.