# PHPExcel_IOFactory::load throwing uncaught Exception and caused script halt

Tags: php, batch-file, phpexcel

i've verified that the file is exists, this is my script to load the document

```
 try{
       $this->obj_global = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($this->file_name);
       $err_msgs = '';

    }catch(ErrorException $e)
    {
        $err_msgs = $e.getMessage();

    }catch (Exception $e)
    {
        $err_msgs = $e.getMessage();

    }
```

i read my log and found, error messages from Excel5.php line 995 with messages contain "Call to a member function getBlipType() on a non-object" as i believed that, the parser try to loads the graphics object and failed. 
btw i've try to read phpexcel discussion forum, and found nothing about the issue. i don't know if this is a bug or the problem comes from my corrupted excel file. but fortunately i can load and read that file correctly without any error when i try to change my loader script and set my reader setReadDataOnly(true); but another problem is, when working with this method, i cannot read my date column correctly.

my question are, how can i caught this type of error, i've try to catch it but it's not working, script just halt?

please any help, i've read this too.
[mark baker(the author of phpexcel) explaination about date type column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394141/phpexcel-issue-for-reading-date-field-from-excel-file)

Comment: I think you want `$e->getMessage()` instead of `$e.getMessage()` in your `catch` blocks.

Comment: indeed, i was wrong writing that style (switch between jScript and php, and forgot the style i was were). :D, but still uncaught exception. :( it's a fatal error caused the script halted.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error message when I tried to read images form an Excel file that contain graphics of "unknown type". So, the solution was to add the missing statement in Excel5.php as follows.

Find and replace:

```
$BSEindex = $spContainer->getOPT(0x0104);
```

with:

```
$BSEindex = $spContainer->getOPT(0x0104);
if (empty($BSEindex)) break;
```

That's it! The Excel5.php file is part of the PHPExcel distribution and the line you need to replace varies.

Answer (score 0):

i think i just find the solution to my own problem, i posted here which purpose if somebody have similar problem. according to the problem, i just need to know which file is failed to process by phpexcel, and i came up to use php function register_shutdown_function( callback function [, mixed parameter [, mixed ...]] ), 
i use it like this.

```
register_shutdown_function(  "clean_exit" );
function clean_exit()
{
    if ( @is_array( $e = @error_get_last() ) ) {
        $code = isset( $e['type'] ) ? $e['type'] : 0;
        $msg = isset( $e['message'] ) ? $e['message'] : '';
        $file = isset( $e['file'] ) ? $e['file'] : '';
        $line = isset( $e['line'] ) ? $e['line'] : '';

        /*if fatal error then check, the source of error*/
        if ( $code == 1 ) {
            /*update imported table by current_id_import*/

            //look for , if it caused by PHPExcel then update imported table
            $match = preg_match('/phpexcel/i', $file);
            if($match==1)
            {
              /*if errors caused by phpexcel then do stuff*/
            }


        }
    }

}
```

this function is called when fatal error happen. 
so that i can log any file which raise the fatal error, problem solve. :D